Keepalived not working to redirect requests
I'm configuring KeepAlived for HA on nginx.
On my configuration, it should work like this:
VIP 1 - 192.168.97.180 (Web pages)
-> Server 1 - 192.168.97.200
-> Server 2 - 192.168.97.230
VIP 2 - 192.168.97.181 (REST APIs)
-> Server 1 - 192.168.97.201
-> Server 2 - 192.168.97.231
The same URL I am testing on 192.168.97.180 should return http 200 BUT on vip 192.168.97.181 should return an 404 not found.
But when I run a curl to test the url, it always returns 404... The impression i get is that it´s redirecting for the server IP 192.168.97.220 and NOT the VIP servers
vrrp_instance VI_1 {
       state MASTER
       interface ens37
       virtual_router_id 01
       priority 150
       advert_int 1
       unicast_src_ip 192.168.97.200
       unicast_peer {
              192.168.97.230
       }
       virtual_ipaddress {
              192.168.97.180/24
       }
}

vrrp_instance VI_2 {
       state MASTER
       interface ens37
       virtual_router_id 02
       priority 150
       advert_int 1
       unicast_src_ip 192.168.97.201
       unicast_peer {
              192.168.97.231
       }
       virtual_ipaddress {
              192.168.97.181/24
       }
}

Keepalived log:
Dec 18 11:59:35 systemd[1]: /usr/lib/systemd/system/keepalived.service:8: PIDFile= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/keepalived.pid â†’ /run/keepalived.pid; please update the unit file accordingly.
Dec 18 11:59:35 systemd[1]: Starting LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor...
Dec 18 11:59:35 Keepalived[81578]: Starting Keepalived v2.3.1 (05/24,2024)
Dec 18 11:59:35 Keepalived[81578]: Running on Linux 5.14.0-427.42.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 18 14:35:40 EDT 2024 (built for Linux 5.14.0)
Dec 18 11:59:35 Keepalived[81578]: Command line: '/usr/sbin/keepalived' '-D'
Dec 18 11:59:35 Keepalived[81578]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf'.
Dec 18 11:59:35 Keepalived[81578]: Configuration file /etc/keepalived/keepalived.conf
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived[81649]: NOTICE: setting config option max_auto_priority should result in better keepalived performance
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived[81649]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=81650
Dec 18 11:59:47 systemd[1]: Started LVS and VRRP High Availability Monitor.
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Registering Kernel netlink reflector
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Registering Kernel netlink command channel
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Assigned address 192.168.97.220 for interface ens37
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) removing VIPs.
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) removing VIPs.
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived[81649]: Startup complete
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE (init)
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) Entering BACKUP STATE (init)
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(  5), family(IPv4), proto(112), fd(13,14) , unicast, address(192.168.97.200)]
Dec 18 11:59:47 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: VRRP sockpool: [ifindex(  5), family(IPv4), proto(112), fd(15,16) , unicast, address(192.168.97.201)]
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) Receive advertisement timeout
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) Entering MASTER STATE
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) setting VIPs.
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) Sending/queueing gratuitous ARPs on ens37 for 192.168.97.180
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Sending gratuitous ARP on ens37 for 192.168.97.180
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) Receive advertisement timeout
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) Entering MASTER STATE
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) setting VIPs.
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) Sending/queueing gratuitous ARPs on ens37 for 192.168.97.181
Dec 18 11:59:50 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Sending gratuitous ARP on ens37 for 192.168.97.181
Dec 18 11:59:55 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_1) Sending/queueing gratuitous ARPs on ens37 for 192.168.97.180
Dec 18 11:59:55 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Sending gratuitous ARP on ens37 for 192.168.97.180
Dec 18 11:59:55 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: (VI_2) Sending/queueing gratuitous ARPs on ens37 for 192.168.97.181
Dec 18 11:59:55 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Sending gratuitous ARP on ens37 for 192.168.97.181
Dec 18 11:59:55 Keepalived_vrrp[81650]: Sending gratuitous ARP on ens37

What am I doing wrong in here ?

I don't think there's any keepalived issue and its logs are likely not relevant. However, it is supposed to choose one of the two Nginx servers, right? These two Nginx instances should generally have the same configuration, what is it, and what's in the Nginx logs? How exactly you tested the availability (e.g. what curl command did you use) and what it sent in the Host HTTP header, and is that hostname configured in the right server block in Nginx? Please, add this information into the question, not as a comment.
